# Arel subselects with ActiveRecord?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I'm using [a slightly-modified version of the geocoded gem](https://github.com/neezer/geocoder) which returns this query when I call `near` on my model (calling `Deal.near(southwest)`, where `southwest` is an array of geo coordinates):

```
SELECT
  deals.*,
  3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((37.772476604436974 - addresses.lat) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(37.772476604436974 * PI() / 180) * COS(addresses.lat * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-122.42336332798004 - addresses.lng) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) )) AS distance,
  CAST(DEGREES(ATAN2( RADIANS(addresses.lng - -122.42336332798004), RADIANS(addresses.lat - 37.772476604436974))) + 360 AS decimal) % 360 AS bearing
  FROM "deals"
  INNER JOIN "companies" ON "companies"."id" = "deals"."company_id"
  INNER JOIN "addresses" ON "addresses"."addressable_id" = "companies"."id" AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = 'Company'
  WHERE (
    addresses.lat BETWEEN 37.483013038215276 AND 38.06194017065867
    AND addresses.lng BETWEEN -122.78956461309022 AND -122.05716204286986
  )
  GROUP BY
    deals.id,
    deals.created_at,
    deals.updated_at,
    deals.active,
    deals.company_id,
    deals.title,
    deals.limitations,
    deals.redemption_count,
    addresses.lat,
    addresses.lng
  HAVING 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((37.772476604436974 - addresses.lat) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(37.772476604436974 * PI() / 180) * COS(addresses.lat * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-122.42336332798004 - addresses.lng) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) )) <= 20
  ORDER BY 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((37.772476604436974 - addresses.lat) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(37.772476604436974 * PI() / 180) * COS(addresses.lat * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-122.42336332798004 - addresses.lng) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) )) ASC
```

My issue is that this will return multiple `Deal` records if that `Deal`'s company has multiple `Address`es, which I don't want.

In MySQL, I could just omit `address.lat, address.lng` in the `GROUP_BY` clause and it will properly group the records, but I can't do this in PostgreSQL.

I know I could wrap the whole query above in another `SELECT` and `GROUP_BY`, like this:

```
SELECT
  id, created_at, updated_at, active, title, punches_to_complete, company_id, description, lat, lng, MIN(distance), bearing
  FROM ( ... ) AS t
  GROUP BY company_id
```

... where the ellipsis is the query from above. That (I believe) should get me the desired result in both MySQL and PostgreSQL.

The only problem is that I have no idea how to write this in ARel!

I had tried the following, a la [this tip](https://github.com/rails/arel/pull/38#issuecomment-1022037) from the ARel guru, but I couldn't really make it work quite right (calling `to_sql` as the OP had said fixed his issue escapes the quotes, which freaks PostgreSQL out).

Can anyone help me with this???

---

***UPDATE***:

I've managed to get this done with an additional scope, like so:

```
  scope :nearest, lambda { |coords|
    subquery = "(#{Deal.near(coords).to_sql}) AS t1"
    columns = Deal.columns.map{ |c| c.name }.join(',')
    Deal.select(columns)
      .select('MIN(distance) AS distance')
      .from(subquery)
      .group(columns)
      .order('distance ASC')
  }
```

However, this totally breaks chainability, as now I cannot call something like `current_user.deals.nearest(coords)`, since that tags on an additional `WHERE deals.user_id = 1` to the query outside of the subselect. I tried compensating for this by moving this logic into a class method and blanking the wheres clause on the SelectManager manually, like this:

```
  def self.nearest(coords)
    subquery = "(#{Deal.near(coords).to_sql}) AS t1"
    columns = Deal.columns.map{ |c| c.name }.join(',')
    query = Deal.select(columns)
      .select('MIN(distance) AS distance')
      .from(subquery)
      .group(columns)
      .order('distance ASC')
    query.arel.ast.cores[0].wheres = []
    query
  end
```

... but that doesn't seem to work either: the additional `WHERE` clause is still appended:

> Failure/Error:
>   @user.deals.nearest(southwest).first.distance.to_f.round(2).should ==
>        ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>          Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'deals.user_id' in 'where
>   clause': SELECT  id,created_at,updated_at,user_id,company_id,
>   MIN(distance) AS distance FROM (SELECT deals.*, 3958.755864232 * 2 *
>   ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((37.772476604436974 - addresses.lat) * PI() / 180
>   / 2), 2) + COS(37.772476604436974 * PI() / 180) * COS(addresses.lat *
>   PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-122.42336332798004 - addresses.lng) * PI() /
>   180 / 2), 2) )) AS distance, CAST(DEGREES(ATAN2( RADIANS(addresses.lng
>   - -122.42336332798004), RADIANS(addresses.lat - 37.772476604436974)))
>   + 360 AS decimal) % 360 AS bearing FROM `deals` INNER JOIN `companies`
>   ON `companies`.`id` = `deals`.`company_id` INNER JOIN `addresses` ON
>   `addresses`.`addressable_id` = `companies`.`id` AND
>   `addresses`.`addressable_type` = 'Company' WHERE `deals`.`user_id` =
>   26 AND (addresses.lat BETWEEN 37.483013038215276 AND 38.06194017065867
>   AND addresses.lng BETWEEN -122.78956461309022 AND -122.05716204286986)
>   GROUP BY
>   deals.id,deals.created_at,deals.updated_at,deals.user_id,deals.company_id,
>   addresses.lat, addresses.lng HAVING 3958.755864232 * 2 *
>   ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((37.772476604436974 - addresses.lat) * PI() / 180
>   / 2), 2) + COS(37.772476604436974 * PI() / 180) * COS(addresses.lat *
>   PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-122.42336332798004 - addresses.lng) * PI() /
>   180 / 2), 2) )) <= 20 ORDER BY 3958.755864232 * 2 *
>   ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((37.772476604436974 - addresses.lat) * PI() / 180
>   / 2), 2) + COS(37.772476604436974 * PI() / 180) * COS(addresses.lat *
>   PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-122.42336332798004 - addresses.lng) * PI() /
>   180 / 2), 2) )) ASC) AS t1  WHERE `deals`.`user_id` = 26 GROUP BY
>   id,created_at,updated_at,user_id,company_id ORDER BY distance ASC
>   LIMIT 1

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with ARel? The additional scopes above feel really dirty to me (parsing the subquery to raw SQL? I thought ARel was supposed to make it so I never did that!)

Related question: Can ARel formulate cross-db queries for CTEs (Common Table Expressions)?